# Error installing underscore using npm

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-2013, npm, underscore.js

I am learning Node.js with Visual Studio 2013. I installed node.js - Node.js Tools 1.1.1 for Visual Studio 2013 from 
https://github.com/Microsoft/nodejstools/releases/tag/v1.1.1
Here are the results from command prompt when I give command - `npm install underscore`

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\project>npm install underscore
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\
node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "underscore"
npm ERR! node v4.6.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.9
npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo

npm ERR! network getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org registry.npmjs.org:443

npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settin
gs.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\project\npm-debug.log

C:\project>
```

Comment: Says it can't find the registry. Address looks right, check your internet connection & settings.

Comment: Forgot to mention that I am using Windows 7 machine

Comment: John, my internet connection is just fine. How else I am accessing stackoverflow? What settings should I check?

Comment: John, It worked. I was on internet but also using VPN. Once I disconnected from VPN it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on the internet via VPN (based on comments) there's a solid shot that your company has some kind of HTTP Proxy in place, especially if your browser works but command line tools (e.g. npm) don't.

Normally setting environmental variables like HTTP_PROXY and https_proxy works well, but I'm honestly not sure if that's true on Windows boxes as well since I got away from developing on them years ago.  The other method is setting it in your npm config:

```
npm config set proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
```